Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.runJob while Running Spark on Windows 11 Local machine
I have the following piece of code
vertices = df1.select(F.explode(F.array('issuer_id_indexed', 'receiver_id_indexed'))) \
.distinct() \
.rdd.map(lambda row: row[0])  # Transform the exploded values into an RDD

# Create an index for each vertex
vertices_with_index = vertices.zipWithIndex().map(lambda x: (x[1], x[0]))  # Swap to (index, value)

# Convert the RDD to a DataFrame with column names 'id' and 'node'
vertex_df = vertices_with_index.toDF(["id", "node"])

# Show the resulting DataFrame
vertex_df.show()

When I try to run the above code, I get the error or traceback bellow

The error seems to come when I call the toDF function on my vertices_with_index in-order to convert it from a pyspark.rdd.PipelinedRDD to a Spark Dataframe.
I am currently trying to run Pyspark on my local machine and I have tried the steps below to try to solve this error with no luck:

Ensured that my env variables are correct
Installed a lower version of Java 8
Increased the amount of resources given to Spark.

Any help will be very much appreciated.

Please include the full error message as text and not as an image, otherwise it is impossible to figure out what the issue is!
